Add More Slides To A Pure CSS Background Slideshow With Ken Burns Effect
Can anyone help me or at least give me an idea how to add 2 more slides to this Pure CSS Slideshow?
Here is the original link: https://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-background-slideshow-ken-burns-effect/
It only supports 4 slides as right now.
I want to add Slide 5 and Slide 6.
The part where I am having the difficulties is the "Ken Burns effect in the CSS keyframes"
@-webkit-keyframes kenburns-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  1.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  23.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  26.5625% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  98.4375% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.21176);
    transform: scale(1.21176);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes kenburns-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  1.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  23.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  26.5625% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  98.4375% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.21176);
    transform: scale(1.21176);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes kenburns-2 {
  23.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  26.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  48.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51.5625% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes kenburns-2 {
  23.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  26.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  48.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51.5625% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes kenburns-3 {
  48.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  51.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  73.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76.5625% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes kenburns-3 {
  48.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  51.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  73.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76.5625% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes kenburns-4 {
  73.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  76.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  98.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes kenburns-4 {
  73.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  76.5625% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  98.4375% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}



Please how a minimal reproducible example. What have you tried? What is the difficulty you are facing?

The source you linked to, Ken Burns effect has a link to a CodePen example and that has the SCSS source for the styling. To add more images, increase the $items value (and compile the SCSS) and add the image links to your HTML code. You can also change the total time for the animation.

First of all you need to clean up the code. You can get rid of all the -webkit properties, they are not needed in 2024.
The other key is to use the same animation sequence for every side, but offset them using animation-delay. That simplifies things a lot.
We set the base style for the slides to include opacity: 0 and transform: scale(1.2). That’s the initial state. Then we define the animation sequence so that the time difference between start fade in and start fade out is one-sixth of the total or 16.67%. If we had eight slides, this difference would be one-eighth or 12.5%.

0% - start fade in, start downscaling
3% - finish fade in
16.67% - start fade out
19.67% - finish fade out, finish downscaling

We assign this same animation sequence to every slide, but specify a different animation-delay for each one. So if we want one cycle of the slideshow to take 24 seconds, we then divide that by 6 to get the additional delay we need to add to each slide.

slide 1 - no delay
slide 2 - animation-delay: 4s
slide 3 - animation-delay: 8s
slide 4 - animation-delay: 12s
slide 5 - animation-delay: 16s
slide 6 - animation-delay: 20s

Here is a snippet to demonstrate. (Note that I have added three extra seconds of delay to everything to allow the remote images time to load.)


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: kenburns;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.slideshow-image:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.slideshow-image:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.slideshow-image:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 11s;
}

.slideshow-image:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

.slideshow-image:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 19s;
}

.slideshow-image:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 23s;
}

@keyframes kenburns {
  3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  19.67% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 1em 2em -1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 1em 2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
<h1>Background Slideshow With Ken Burns Effect Demo</h1>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-image" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1600/1400?image=492')"></div>
  <div class="slideshow-image" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1600/1400?image=487')"></div>
  <div class="slideshow-image" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1600/1400?image=483')"></div>
  <div class="slideshow-image" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1600/1400?image=478')"></div>
  <div class="slideshow-image" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1600/1400?image=201')"></div>
  <div class="slideshow-image" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1600/1400?image=202')"></div>
</div>



